# Does the Solana CLI support setting a priority fee?

Tags: solana-cli

I am a bit confused in that ChatGPT is reporting that the Solana CLI supports setting a priority fee using the `--priority` option like so:

```
solana transfer 10 SOL --from <SOURCE_WALLET_ADDRESS> --to <DESTINATION_WALLET_ADDRESS> --priority 128
```

But when I try the example I get an error:

```
error: Found argument '--priority' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

The CLI help file does NOT mention the `--priority` option. I can accept the ChatGPT is in error. I just want to make sure from someone expert on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It's only available on master at the moment, but you'll be able to use the new `--with-compute-unit-price` flag, ie:

```
solana transfer --with-compute-unit-price 10 3pGiHDDek35npQuyWQ7FGcWxqJdHvVPDHDDmBFs2YxQj 10
```

And here's its help text:

```
        --with-compute-unit-price <COMPUTE-UNIT-PRICE>
            Set compute unit price for transaction, in increments of 0.000001 lamports per compute unit.
```

Once 1.16 branches off of master, you'll be able to use it! Or you can build the CLI from source yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you cant set priority fee with the cli yet. Feel free to check this out for more info https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage and which features cli supports rn