# Set priority fees when deploying with solana cli

Tags: solana-cli

According to [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/does-the-solana-cli-support-setting-a-priority-fee), we can set a priority fee with the cli when sending a transfer. Is there a way to do this when deploying programs using the cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Solana toolsuite CLI you can in version `1.18.8`.

You use the flag `--with-compute-unit-price` along with your priority fee in microlamports when deploying a program.

So it'd look like:

`solana program deploy TARGET.so --with-compute-unit-price 1`

for deploying `TARGET.so` with a compute unit price of 1 microlamport.